# Can a lower subdivision be used when navigating the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

In zbrush when you rotate/pan/zoom a hi-poly sculpt in the viewport it seems to swap in a lower subdivision giving the impression of faster drawing. Does Blender have any such feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in the options panel of sculpt mode, you have this : fast navigate

[image]